# MDX: Find the sales value of a two week specified date range a specific year and previous year

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I'm creating a data set where I eventually want to compare a specific two week date range a specific year (2014) and the same weeks previous year (i.e. two weeks up to the last date of the specified date range).

What I have done thus far is to create the Query to find the relevant data for the specified two week date range as this:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { 
    [Measures].[Quantity], [Measures].[Total Price]
   ,[Measures].[Contribution Margin], [Measures].[Profit Margin]
    } ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY { 
        ( [Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-20]:[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-30]
   ,[Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[1024] )
    } on rows
from [DSV_FactStoreSales 1]
```

I don't understand how I get the same period the previous year. I have looked at `ParallelPeriod`, but the examples I've seen has included `currentmember`, but in this example I have a specified range, spanning two weeks.

Does anyone have any idea how to implement this? I need this to be in the same Query, in order to be able to utilize the result set as a data set in SSRS.

> EDIT

I ran the Query:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { 
        [Measures].[Quantity]
        ,[Measures].[Total Price]
        ,[Measures].[Contribution Margin]
        ,[Measures].[Profit Margin]
    } ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY 
        { 
            (
                parallelperiod([Dim Date].[Calender].[Year],1,[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-17])
                :
                parallelperiod([Dim Date].[Calender].[Year],1,[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-30]),[Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[1024] 
            )
        } on rows
from [DSV_FactStoreSales 1]
```

but it gave me the result set:

```
            Quantity    Total Price Contribution Margin Profit Margin
2014-11-07  1024    1   119.2       47.04               39.46%
2014-11-10  1024    1   31.6        21.1                66.77%
2014-11-25  1024    1   55.2        25.45               46.11%
2014-11-26  1024    2   110.8       65.78               59.37%
2014-11-28  1024    166 20903.62    9101.82             43.54%
2014-11-29  1024    117 11870.75    5535                46.63%
2014-11-30  1024    50  9148.8      4008.13             43.81%
2014-12-01  1024    91  11574.39    4933.01             42.62%
2014-12-02  1024    21  2776.8      1254.12             45.16%
```

where the dates in particular seems off compared to the sought-after effect.

> EDIT 2

I've tried the query

```
Select Non empty {[Measures].[Total Price]} on 0,
([Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].members) on 1
FROM (Select
        {
            (parallelperiod([Dim Date].[Calender].[Month],4,[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-22])
            :parallelperiod([Dim Date].[Calender].[mONTH],4,[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-14-28]), [Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[1041])
        } on columns
from [DSV_FactStoreSales 1])
```

but that resulted in showing sales from `2014-07-26` through `2018-05-02`. May there be some underlying hierarchy error, or have I misinterpreted `ParallelPeriod()`? `Please note` that I did some testing on `Month` in this last example Query.

> EDIT 3 "Using the With MEMBER approach"

I've also tried the suggested solution to invoke `WITH Member AS` like this:

```
With
Member [Measures].[QuantityParallelPeriod] as
(
    ParallelPeriod([Dim Date].[Calender].[Year],1,[Dim Date].[Calender].CurrentMember),
    [Measures].[Quantity]
)
Select Non empty {[Measures].[QuantityParallelPeriod],[Measures].[Total Price]} on 0,
non empty{([Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].members)} on 1
FROM (Select
        {
            (parallelperiod([Dim Date].[Calender].[MOnth],4,[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-22])
            :parallelperiod([Dim Date].[Calender].[MOnth],4,[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-28]), [Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[1024])
        } on columns
from [DSV_FactStoreSales 1])
```

but that resulted in

```
                        Quantity
                        Parallel
                        Period  Total Price
            2014-11-07  (null)  119.2
            2014-11-10  (null)  31.6
            2014-11-25  (null)  55.2
            2014-11-26  (null)  110.8
            2014-11-28  (null)  20903.62
            2014-11-29  (null)  11870.75
            2014-11-30  (null)  9148.8
            2014-12-01  (null)  11574.39
            2014-12-02  (null)  2776.8
            2015-11-13  1       (null)
            2015-11-16  1       (null)
            2015-12-01  91      (null)
            2015-12-02  21      (null)
```

I don't understand how only dates `Outside` the specified `parallelperiod range` returns a value?

> EDIT Expected Output

What I'd expect as an output would be:

```
                    Quantity    TotalPrice      Contribution margin     ProfitMargin
      2013-11-17    4           5               13                      23 %
      2013-11-18    4           5               15                      25 %
      .             .           .               .                       .
      .             .           .               .                       .
      .             .           .               .                       .
      2013-11-30    1           100             80                      80 %
      2014-11-17    1           100             80                      80 %
      2014-11-18    1           100             80                      80 %
      .             .           .               .                       .
      .             .           .               .                       .
      .             .           .               .                       .
      2014-11-30    1           100             80                      80 %
```

(where the numeric values are dummy values and may no add up "logically")

Answer (score 2):

It will return you the same period set 1 year before:

```
{
    ParallelPeriod([Dim Date].[Calender].[Year],1,[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-20])
    :
    ParallelPeriod([Dim Date].[Calender].[Year],1,[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-30])
}
```

In order to add calculated measure with last year:

```
With
Member [Measures].[QuantityParallelPeriod] as
(
    ParallelPeriod([Dim Date].[Calender].[Year],1,[Dim Date].CurrentMember),
    [Measures].[Quantity]
)
```

The full code must look like the following:

```
With
Member [Measures].[QuantityParallelPeriod] as
(
    ParallelPeriod([Dim Date].[Calender].[Year],1,[Dim Date].[Calender].CurrentMember),
    [Measures].[Quantity]
)

Select
Non empty {[Measures].[Quantity],[Measures].[QuantityParallelPeriod]} on 0,
Non empty {[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-20]:[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-30]} on 1
From [DSV_FactStoreSales 1]
Where ([Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[1024])
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I've added that into the Query, but then I get the output outlined in my Edit. Using ParallellPeriod, is it possible to have the sale values of the specified date range *and* the sales of the specified date range the previous year in the same result set? From my understanding, it returns the previous year's sales exclusively?

Comment: I tried this as well. I've updated the OP under `EDIT 3` with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shot at a working solution. If this isn't the shape of the final working query you want please clarify as I didn't catch that in your question.

```
WITH
MEMBER [Dim Date].[Calender].[All].[Prior Year] as
Aggregate(
 {
            parallelperiod([Dim Date].[Calender].[Year],1,[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-17])
                :
            parallelperiod([Dim Date].[Calender].[Year],1,[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-30])
 }
)
MEMBER [Dim Date].[Calender].[All].[Current Year] as
Aggregate(
 {
            [Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-17]
             :
             [Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-30]
 }
)

SELECT { 
    [Measures].[Quantity], [Measures].[Total Price]
   ,[Measures].[Contribution Margin], [Measures].[Profit Margin]
    } ON COLUMNS,
    {[Dim Date].[Calender].[All].[Prior Year],
     [Dim Date].[Calender].[All].[Current Year]}
    on rows
from [DSV_FactStoreSales 1] 
Where [Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[1024]
```

Per your clarifying expected results, here is another shape:

```
SELECT { 
    [Measures].[Quantity], [Measures].[Total Price]
   ,[Measures].[Contribution Margin], [Measures].[Profit Margin]
    } ON COLUMNS,
    {
     {
            parallelperiod([Dim Date].[Calender].[Year],1,[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-17])
                :
            parallelperiod([Dim Date].[Calender].[Year],1,[Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-30])
        },

        {
            [Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-17]
             :
             [Dim Date].[Calender].[Date].[2014-11-30]
        }
    }
    on rows
from [DSV_FactStoreSales 1] 
Where [Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[1024]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Running your query on a test store - with `StoreKey = 1041` whose only sales are between `2015-05-12:2015-05-18`, I get that the PriorYear's sales are 342 (which is the total amount of sales in may,2015 for store 1041), and the CurrentYear is (null). But I'd expect an output which I will update in the OP soon. Do you know why the program chooses to enlist the 2015 year's sales as the PriorYear? I'd expect the PriorYear of 2014-11-17 to be in 2013.

Comment: @Cenderze how do you have your year level in your Calendar hierarchy sorted? Do older years come first?

Comment: I have set up Dim Date to be a YQMWD hierarchy. I'm not sure how to check the ordering of a specific level. I'm using the default values as of now (I have however "pointed" my levels to eachother, i.e. Quarter points to Year, Month points to Quarter etc.)

Comment: @Cenderze in Excel if you put the Calendar hierarchy into the filters section if a PivotTable and pop down the drop down I assume it reads 2013, 2014, etc not 2014, 2013?

Comment: What version of SSAS?

Comment: SSAS 2015. I am using SQL Server Enterprise edition. When I browse the cube the years behaves like `2009`,`2010`,`...`,`2018`

Comment: @Cenderze I can't explain why ParallelPeriod didn't work right. Can you try my new query in my answer?